# Batch "if" statement, only going to do something if text is entered, else go do something else

Tags: batch-file, input, user-input

I have a batch script that has a user input:

```
set /p serverstart=Starter Path (or leave blank if unknown):
```

Now what needs to happen is if a user inputs something (anything) it will go to a specific label:

```
if %serverstart% == [anything] goto %serverstart%
:%serverstart%
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar %serverstart%.jar nogui
```

But only if the user inputs something. If the user leaves the field blank, the file needs to continue on it's way:

```
set /p serverstart=Starter Path (or leave blank if unknown): 
:serverram
cls
set /p serverram=Server RAM: 
[enter more code here]
```

So, if the user inputs something it goes to the defined user label, and starts the %serverstart%.jar, but if the user leaves the field blank it does nothing and carries on. Would:

```
set /p serverstart=Starter Path (or leave blank if unknown): 
if %serverstart% == "" goto %serverstart%
goto serverram
:serverram
set /p serverram=Server RAM: 

:%serverstart%
java -Xmx%serverram%M -Xms%serverram%M -jar %serverstart%.jar nogui
```

work?

(Just incase you want it, here is the full code so far)

```
@ECHO OFF
title MineServer Runner
cls

:servername
cls
if exist ServerFiles\serverconfig.cmd goto startserver
set /p servername=Server Name: 
echo set servername=%servername%>> ServerFiles\serverconfig.cmd
call "ServerFiles\serverconfig.cmd"
title MineServer (%servername%) Runner
set /p serverstart=Starter Path (or leave blank if unknown): 
:serverram
cls
set /p serverram=Server RAM: 
echo set serverram=%serverram%>> ServerFiles\serverconfig.cmd

:startserver
cd ServerFiles
call "serverconfig.cmd"
java -Xmx%serverram%M -Xms%serverram%M -jar starters\minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if defined serverstart goto (wehaveinput) else (goto wedonthaveinput)
```

You can of course use `if not defined serverstart...` also.

An remember - `set` your variable to empty (`set "var=") before`set/p` else it will remain unchanged from any prior value it had.

Comment: @Stephan : As you say. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

i would turn it around:

```
if not "%serverstart%" == "" (
  we have input-code
) ELSE (
  we have NO input-code
)
```

Edited.

Comment: The dot is not required: `if not "%serverstart%" == "" (` will work _always_. "i don't really now when, but sometimes the leading whitespaces are trimmed". Do you have any example that prove this point? It is not a good idea to post suggestions based on suppositions...

Comment: edited. haven't an example at the moment. it sometimes appears at work, where i'm doing a lot with batch, next time, it appears, i'll write it down and come back here ^.^ ;)